# How can I tell Pandas read_csv to use multiple whitespaces as separators but not single whitespaces?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I want to read in a Pandas dataframe from csv, where there are single whitespaces inside column names and the separators are multiple whitespaces. How can I tell Pandas to use only more than one consecutive whitespace as separator but ignore single whitespaces?

Answer (score 6):

With specific regex pattern for `sep=` option:

```
df = pd.read_csv(sep='\s{2,}')
```

- `\s{2,}` - quantifier, matches any whitespace character between `2` and unlimited times, as many times as possible

Answer (score 3):

another option that I actually use, which saves me some `shift` keypresses:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep='\s\s+')
```